# Swift 3: stringByReplacingCharactersInRange alternatives

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, range, swift3

Any of you knows an `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` to be use in Swift 3?

I'm trying to convert this `Objective-C` to `Swift`:

```
strToSort = [strToSort stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange((i-1),1) withString: [strToSort substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((i),1)]];
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift 3 it is.

```
strToSort = strToSort.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: str)
```

**Note:** Here range is type of Swift `Range<String.Index>` object not `NSRange`.

For more details on `Range` check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range).

**Ex:**

```
let str = "Apple"
let i = 3
let range = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i-1)..<str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
let subStringRange = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)..<str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i+1)
print(str.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: str.substring(with: subStringRange)))
```

**Output:**

```
Aplle
```

Comment: I create the range as follow let rangeOne = strToSort.index(strToSort.startIndex, offsetBy: (i-1)). But I'm getting this error:  error: cannot convert value of type 'String.Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index') to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')

Comment: @user2924482 I haven't know that you have asked for how to make range, but yesterday I don't why someone down voted the answer, and then I shown your comment, So I have edited my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

quick way, using NSString

`let strToSort: NSString = "string to sort"
let newString = strToSort.replacingCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(0, 6), with: "")
print(newString) // to sort`

Hope it helps